# emmeans: regrid() for binomial GLMM with user-defined link function

Tags: r, mixed-models, emmeans

I have fitted a binomial GLMM in R with a modified link function with a fixed guessing probability as suggested in [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q4/004531.html) - except that the guessing probability is 1/2 and not 1/3. Therefore the sigmoidal activation in my case becomes:
P(correct) = 0.5 + 0.5*(exp(term)/(1 + exp(term))).

My model looks like this:

```
library(lme4)

m = 2
mod = glmer(correct ~ group*stim_strength + (stim_strength|subject) , 
            family=binomial(link=mafc.logit(m)), data=obs_data)
```

where: guessing probability is 1/`m`; `correct` is a categorical variable indicating correct/incorrect response; `group` is a factor with two levels; `stim_strength` is numerical with values in [0,1]; `mafc.logit` is the function suggested in the [thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mixed-models/2010q4/004531.html).
I'm essentially fitting separate psychometric curves of the stimulus strength (`stim_strength`) for the two groups, while taking into account the inter-subject fluctuations in slope and intercept (random effect structure `(stim_strength|subject)`)

This is what I get:

```
plot_model(mod, type = 'emm', terms = c('stim_strength', 'group'))
```

[---> plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7sr9.png)

The model describes the data nicely, and I now want to perform some post-hoc analyses on it. Specifically, I want to run for example:

```
mod.emm = emmeans(mod, ~group|stim_strength, at=list(stim_strength=c(.25,.75)))
confint(regrid(mod.emm))
contrast(regrid(mod.emm), 'pairwise', simple = 'group', combine = TRUE, adjust = 'holm')
```

i.e. compute confidence intervals for the %correct of the two groups at some specified values of `stim_strength`, and compare the %correct of the two groups at these values.

Note that **I'm using regrid()**, because I want the analyses to be done on the back-transformed values, not on the linear part of the model!
However, `regrid()` won't work with a user-defined link function. In fact, the `regrid` is just ignored here, as you can see e.g. from the output of the `confint()` call above (estimates are labelled as `prob` but they're clearly not transformed to [.5,1]):

```
stim_strength = 0.25:
 group   prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1     -1.329 0.173 Inf    -1.716    -0.942
 2     -0.553 0.161 Inf    -0.913    -0.192

stim_strength = 0.75:
 group   prob    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 1      1.853 0.372 Inf     1.018     2.687
 2      3.375 0.395 Inf     2.489     4.261
```

Similarly, when adding `type='response'` in `emmeans`, I get the message:

```
Unknown transformation "mafc.logit(2)": no transformation done
```

**Any workaround?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the linked suggestion, it appears that `mafc.logit()` is a function that returns a list with all the information needed to implement the transform. All you need to do is update the `emmGrid` object with that information:

```
mod.emm <- update(mod.emm, tran = mafc.logit(2))
confint(regrid(mod.emm), adjust = 'holm')
# etc...
```

See, for example, [this vignette section](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#after) and possibly other parts of that vignette.